# 301 redirects and non-existent directories

Tags: seo, htaccess, 301-redirect, directory

I just wanted to clarify something; my boss often messes up and tells a customer to go to a specific directory; i.e. `mysite.co.uk/directory/` instead of the actual correct URL `mysite.co.uk/this_page.html`.

As the customer is normally about to look at the page I add a 301 redirect in the *.htaccess* page so it redirects them from the non-existent directory to the correct page.

Is this a sensible idea, will it eventually lead to slowing down the load time of the website and does it affect any SEO or ranking?

Comment: It's probably more sensible than telling your boss that he's doing something wrong ;-) I don't think the redirect would impact your website or SEO performance.

Comment: Haha, I have told him, he's not a IT inclined person though and gets bored... @Zistoloen was it Necessary to add in some of those edits, some of them are eactly the same as they were?

Comment: @Switchfire: community works to force one formatting for all posts to keep the website homogeneous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will it eventually lead to slowing down the load time of the website

Adding thousands of rules to your `.htaccess` file is not a good idea.  If the `.htaccess` file gets too big, then it could impact the performance of the webserver.  I routinely see `.htaccess` files with hundreds of lines and they perform just fine.  You would have to add lots of these rules to get to the point where there would be performance problems.

> does it affect any SEO or ranking

Google will likely never know that these redirects are in place as they are meant just for users that are told about incorrect URLs.  As such, there is almost no chance that they will affect how your site ranks either positively or negatively.    If somebody does link to one of these URLs that redirects, then Googlebot could find that URL and crawl it.  In such a case, having the redirect is better than not having it because Googlebot would otherwise encounter a 404 error and not pass authority to your website from the link.

---

Besides adding redirects to your .htaccess, you could think about enabling [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) on your Apache server.  With MultiViews, `/this_page.html` can also be accessed as `/this_page` which might eliminate the need for many of your redirects.  Unfortunately, MultiViews creates duplicate content by serving the same page at different URLs instead of issuing redirects.  From an SEO standpoint, you'd want to make sure you have [rel canonical meta tags](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en) on all your pages before you started using MultiViews.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may impact your SEO performance: when Google get 404 responce and at the same time 301 responce, it may make it think you try to manipulate some factors, and it may cause some sanctions.

Comment: You can't get a 301 and 404. You get one or the other.